# Testing for mean difference in 3 subjects for a group of students

Tags: anova, paired-data, independence

I am sorry if this is a naive question, but I wanted to have your suggestions before considering anything. Suppose I have a group of "n" students and I have their score in three courses: A, B, and C. If the scores are not on the same scale, I can standardize them before comparison. For comparing the mean difference between two courses I could have done the Paired-T test, but I am not sure about the extension of paired T-test for comparing more than two means for dependent data. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try the two-way ANOVA. Testing three paired-T test is not appropriate here.

Comment: If you standardize the grades within course, all courses will have a mean of zero.  Obviously, then, there will no difference between courses in mean score.

Comment: @Jianfeng Could you please explain what will be the factors for two-way ANOVA?

Comment: @JoelW. Thank you for pointing that out. By standardize I meant I will convert all the scores under the same scale (eg. score out of 100)

Comment: @curiousmind, one factor is course and the other factor is student, since the scores from the same student are correlated.

Comment: @Jianfeng I see. So, by doing a two-way ANOVA, we are taking care of the correlation of the scores for the same student while our primary interest still lies to see if there is a mean difference among the course scores. Am I getting it right?

Comment: @curiousmind, yes.

Comment: @Jianfeng Excellent! Thanks Jian for the well put suggestion!

Comment: Look up repeated-measures ANOVA. In some circumstances they have greater power than a plain ANOVA.

Comment: See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6T6dvrwDe_U

Answer (score 0):

A simple and intuitive solution is to just do three different paired t-tests and then correct for multiple comparisons using [bonferroni correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonferroni_correction). Approximately this means you just divide your alpha level with the number of comparisons you are doing.